# jQuery .done after AJAX callback

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run some stuff after an AJAX call is completed:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: //do stuff
}).done(function (){
    $('#listings').fadeIn(800).done(function(){
        $('#loading').fadeOut(800);
    });
});
```

This doesn't do the last part which is `$('#loading').fadeOut(800);`, which should start when `$('#listings').fadeIn(800)` is done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fadeIn()` is not really the sort of function that returns a promise, but it does have a callback function you can use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
}).done(function (){
    $('#listings').fadeIn(800, function(){
        $('#loading').fadeOut(800);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Alexander - depends, attaching a promise to a method used on a single elements, that already has a built in callback, does'nt make much sense. The promise method was intended for a sligthly [**different use**](http://api.jquery.com/promise/#example-1)

Answer (score 6):

To get the promise object from an animation, use `.promise`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: handler
}).done(function (){
    $('#listings').fadeIn(800).promise().done(function(){
        $('#loading').fadeOut(800);
    });
});
```

In this particular case, it makes more sense to use a callback rather than `.promise` and `.done` on the animation. The advantage of using `.promise` is it results in a single callback for all selected elements rather than one callback per element. Since you're only animating one element, the callback would be the best way to do it. (adeneo's answer)

There are other advantages to using .promise, but you don't appear to need them. (`$.when` for example)

Comment: because the jQuery object itself is not a promise object. the jqXHR object does however implement the same interface as a promise object.

Comment: "because the jQuery object itself is not a promise object." meaning `.fadeIn()` is not a promise object.

Comment: .fadeIn() returns a jQuery object, and jQuery objects do not implement the promise interface (they lack the .done etc methods). calling .promise() gives you a promise object from the jQuery object that resolves when all current animations on the elements that were contained within the jQuery object complete.